# How to select multiple items with duplicate items using jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON file which contains a list like this;

```json
[{
    "host": "cat",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "id": "cherry"
}, {
    "host": "dog",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "id": "apple"
}, {
    "host": "cat",
    "ip": "192.168.1.2",
    "id": "banana"
}]
```

I want to collect IPs and print `id` and `host` next to it but if `IP` is used multiple times then print multiple `id` and `host` next to instead of a new line. `IP` and `host` can be the same for multiple items but `id` is unique.

So the final output should look like this;

```
$ echo <something>
192.168.1.1 cat cherry dog apple
192.168.1.2 cat banana
```

How can I do this using bash and jq?

Comment: Your example isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a valid JSON file: Remove the last comma `,` in each object to get this as your `input.json`:

```json
[{
    "host": "cat",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "id": "cherry"
}, {
    "host": "dog",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "id": "apple"
}, {
    "host": "cat",
    "ip": "192.168.1.2",
    "id": "banana"
}]
```

Then, you only need one `jq` call:

```
jq --raw-output 'group_by(.ip)[] | [first.ip, (.[] | .host, .id)] | join(" ")' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/25uNzzwWE_)

Comment: hi @pmf both your and Shawn's answer work and solves my problem exactly the same way, what's the difference?

Comment: No significant differences. The most notable is that I `join` your items with a blank space whereas @Shawn uses the `@tsv` builtin which internally joins using tabs.

Comment: Is there a builtin similar to `@tsv` but joins with spaces ?

Comment: No, there is also `@csv` for producing _comma-separated values_ but for others (including multi-character separators) you have to `join` (or construct using `+`) manually. On the other hand, the builtins automatically escape item characters that would collide with the separator character, which with `join` you have to accomplish also manually.

Answer (score 2):

Once you fix your example so it's valid JSON, the `group_by` function is the key:

```sh
$  jq -r 'group_by(.ip)[] | [.[0].ip, map(.host, .id)[]] | @tsv' input.json
192.168.1.1     cat     cherry  dog     apple
192.168.1.2     cat     banana
```

That will combine all objects with the same ip field into an array of objects. The rest is just turning those array of objects into arrays of just the values you want, and finally outputting each new array as a line of tab-separated values.

Comment: hi @Shawn both your and pmf's answer work and solves my problem exactly the same way, what's the difference?

Comment: Heh, I didn't even notice someone else answered at the same time I did. Difference looks to be how the output lines are constructed.